# typescript, type 'never' can assign to every type

Tags: typescript

```
const a:never[]=[]

const b:string[] = a // never[] CAN assign to string[]

const c=(d:never)=>{}
c(1) // number cant assign to never

const d =(e:string[])=>{}
d(a) // never[] CAN assign to string[]

const e = (f:never[])=>{}
e(b) // string[] cant assign to never[]

const f:never = 1 as never

const g:string = f // never CAN assign to string

console.log(g.toLowerCase()) // runtime error!!
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgLjAUwG7IE4G0C6BeXAWACgTRJYAjBaDASzAHNcY94YB6DmFdbHGAGEAggDl4ECHUZgYUEDFoNmOEmXDQYwPAAoAJkjSYAlHgB8AbwC%20ZHQEZjnbmACuAW0qYtcMLDiTpWXkeIww1YnJNPVYdZBooeiZcU0sbYj0dOEcuEL4WEXF-KRk5BSUk1VIIjVhkVhgdADNDPJwU6xJkHUps7nKVb18JYqCFXkwiKsjYZvGMersJXMxw6ZhGeMTGesanZfmC4cDSxQTlVY0QABtkADorkEYdRlv5ABkQAHdMQX8u416MAwLl8dDcdUwGBAGAAhDCgA)

what is the typescript justification of able to assign `never` to other types?

it can cause runtime error as shown in the last line of the code

Comment: _The `never` type is a subtype of, and assignable to, **every** type; however, no type is a subtype of, or assignable to, `never` (except `never` itself). Even `any` isn’t assignable to `never`._ https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never

Comment: What's the point of the examples above?